# Post on Facebook brand page with Spring Social

Tags: java, facebook, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

My module is going to be a RESTful web-service which will have end-points to perform various operations on Facebook brand page (such as post or retrieve comments and likes). This is why there will be no concept of already logged in user or existing browser session. I am having trouble finding correct code snippet to suit my needs. I came across a couple of examples but they all made use of access tokens derived from already logged in users. I might be missing something. Can anyone please point me to right direction?
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use a page access token.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. Do you have any code snippet making use of page access token? I am reading up on page access tokens on Facebook developer's site.